# How to show dots when the text exceeds the size of the Text?

Tags: java, swt

When the content of a the `Text` exceeds the width of the `Text`, I want to show dots (`...`) at the end of the text field.

I have tried to using a `ModifyListener` without success. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

```
  @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



           if (wakeupPatternText.getText().length()>=12) {


               String wakeuppattern=wakeupPatternText.getText(0, 11);




               String dot="...";

              String wakeup=wakeuppattern+dot;
 wakeupPatternText.setText(wakeup);




        }      


        }
    });
```

Comment: If you tried something, please always explain what you tried.

Comment: Can you print out any log and debug it? If you need help, show us the code snippet you wrote; the import part should be the listener, it should substring the Text within it.

Comment: @Baz I have tried to add a modify listener  but main problem is suppose i have 30 character text and my textbox only supports 15 character i am appending .. but as my buttons are binded with textbox all get disabled as (..)are treated as  a invalid value .

Comment: Do not vote down if you are not getting my question please leave comment....

Comment: @Rajesh The reason for the downvotes is most likely the fact, that you didn't post any code and didn't explain what you tried. I am sure that most people understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Baz  please check the code which i have tried to use before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
private static String textContent = "";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            Text text = (Text) e.widget;
            textContent = text.getText();

            text.setText(textContent.substring(0, Math.min(10, textContent.length())) + "...");
        }
    });

    text.addListener(SWT.FocusIn, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            Text text = (Text) e.widget;

            text.setText(textContent);
        }
    });

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Lose focus");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

It listens to focus events and truncates the visible `String` if it is too long.

This is how it looks:

With focus:

[image]

Without focus:

[image]

---

The reason why your code isn't working is the following: When you call `wakeupPatternText.setText(wakeup);` from within the `VerifyListener` the listener itself is called again recursively.

Comment: @Rajesh You're welcome. As I said, people are more motivated to help, if they see what you already tried and where exactly you are stuck.